# How i can assign a object from another object in JSP?

Tags: java, spring, jsp, spring-mvc, controller

I am using Spring MVC .

And I have a method in controller which before returning a jsp puts a object in `ModelMap`.

```
modemap.put("Members",members);
```

Students is a POJO having a  List and List.

Now in my jsp there is a place where I need to store the Student[0] in the variable in jsp.

I dont want to iterate over a list of students at that point. Otherwise I would have used for each loop in  Java.

When I do

```
<c:set var="stu1" value="$(memebrs.student[0]}"></c:set>
```

But this gives me Page not found.

How I can do this?
Thanks in advance.

Comment: The line <c:set var="stu1" value="$(memebrs.student[0]}"></c:set> won't create page not found error, you might have problem with from action url

Answer (score 1):

There seems to be a typo:

```
<c:set var="stu1" value="$(memebrs.student[0]}"></c:set>
```

instead of

```
<c:set var="stu1" value="$(Members.student[0]}"></c:set>
```

(spelling of members in the `map` and `c:set` is different)